# Prioritizing Duplicates Based on Criteria

Tags: sql, email, duplicates

I have a table of data that contains duplicate email addresses. Each email address has a date, a color (values: "Black", "Blue", or "Green"), and a unique ID. There may be sets of duplicate email addresses that contain more than two email addresses (i.e. I may have 10 of duplicates of the same email address) and each set of duplicate email addresses may contain the same or different colors compared to those in its respective duplicate set.

My objective is to retrieve the IDs for email addresses that have a certain color and the max(date). I would like to prioritize the color (first "Black" then "Blue" then "Green") and then move to the max(date) only if there are two or more email addresses within the same duplicate set that have the same highest desired color.

### Example 1

```
ID          Email          Color             Date
1           xyz@xyz.com    Black             01/01/2014
2           xyz@xyz.com    Black             01/31/2014  
3           xyz@xyz.com    Blue              03/31/2015
4           xyz@xyz.com    Green             01/01/2014
5           xyz@xyz.com    Green             01/01/2014
```

### Example 2

```
ID          Email          Color             Date
6           abc@abc.com    Green             12/31/2014
7           abc@abc.com    Green             01/01/2014
8           abc@abc.com    Blue              01/31/2014
```

---

In Example 1, I would want to choose ID 2 as this is the highest desired color of the set of duplicate email addresses--"Black"--and I am choosing the one with max(date).

In Example 2, I would want to choose ID 8 as this is the highest desired color of the set of duplicate email addresses--"Blue".

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm using postgresql, which doesn't work with the syntax provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign priority numbers to each record within every group of duplicate emails as per your requirements. Then, in an outer query, you can select records from each group with the highest priority:

```
SELECT ID, Email, Color
FROM (
SELECT ID, Email, Color,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email 
                          ORDER BY (CASE Color 
                                       WHEN 'Black' THEN 1 
                                       WHEN 'Blue' THEN 2 
                                       ELSE 3 
                                    END),                          
                                    Date DESC) AS rn
FROM emails ) e
WHERE e.rn = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/90520/6)